# How does Regulator invention work?

Tags: tesla-vs-lovecraft

In Tesla vs Lovecraft how does the regulator perk work? It states that it shuffles the perk offerings for new perks. How does this work and how can I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each level in this upgrade, you get to press "shuffle" button in the perk selection screen. It gives you two new choices to choose from.